# How does the default recent posts widget work with cache?

Tags: widgets, cache, customization

I am trying to build a widget based on the default wordpress recent posts widget. In wp-includes/default-widget.php , I noticed in `class WP_Widget_Recent_Posts` in function widget(), the recent posts are first looked for in cache and if not found, then output buffering is turned on and the result is generated and then stored back into the cache. Since I am using NuSphere IDE , I put a `DebugBreak();` inside the condition
 `if ( isset( $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] ) )` (`DebugBreak()` causes a breakpoint exception to occur in the current process.) but the breakpoint was never executed pointing out that the cache wasn't set before. Now this shouldn't be the case as the cache does get set by `wp_cache_set('widget_recent_posts', $cache, 'widget');`. This is my first dilemma.

Secondly, I would really appreciate if someone threw some light on how output buffering works. Cause as I mentioned before, the recent posts are first looked for in cache and if not present there then output buffering is turned on (`ob_start();`), result is fetched and then `ob_get_flush();` is performed like `$cache[$args['widget_id']] = ob_get_flush();` and the cache is set. So if no output is echoed to the browser, then how does the widget actually display the recent posts? PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a memcached-type plugin installed, `wp_cache_set` will only store data for the duration of the current script. Call or add the widget again in the same instance & you'll see it utilise the cache.

As for `ob_get_flush()`, [taken from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php):

> Flush the output buffer, return it as a string and turn off output buffering

In other words, it prints **and** returns the buffer at the same time.

Comment: Got it! Called the widget() twice in a loop and the cache worked :) . And I didn't reckon that flush output buffer = print output buffer. I simply interpreted it as clear output buffer. Everything is crystal clear now. Thanks! :)